# How to load URL in UIWebView in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8

I have the following code:

```
UIWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "google.ca")))
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'NSURLRequest' is not convertible to UIWebView.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Note that the "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" approach (just google) seems to be more 2016. hope it helps someone

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[loadRequest:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadRequest:) is an instance method, not a class method. You should be attempting to call this method with an instance of UIWebview as the receiver, not the class itself.

```
webviewInstance.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "google.ca")!))
```

However, as @radex correctly points out below, you can also take advantage of currying to call the function like this:

```
UIWebView.loadRequest(webviewInstance)(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "google.ca")!))
```

Swift 5

```
webviewInstance.load(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "google.ca")! as URL) as URLRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks. I hooked up @IBOutlet and got it working. This is so awesome! :)

Comment: @0x7fffffff Not a bug. Instance methods in Swift are curried class methods that take the instance object as its first parameter behind the scenes. So you can, in essence, say `UIWebView.loadRequest(webviewInstance)(…)`

Comment: Swift 3 version:  

`webviewInstance.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "google.ca")! as URL) as URLRequest)`

Comment: Swift 4.2 version: 'webviewInstance.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "google.ca")))'

Answer (score 40):

UIWebView in Swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL (string: "url here")
        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if you want to use webkit

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.webView.frame.size.height))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    
     if let url = URL (string: "your URL") {
        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.webView.load(requestObj)
    }
}
```

Comment: whats an issue occur

Comment: 'loadRequest' has been renamed to 'load(_:)'

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

1. Add UIWebView to View.
2. Connect UIWebview outlet using assistant editor and name your "webview".
3. UIWebView Load URL.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
       // Your webView code goes here
      let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")
      let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
      webView.load(requestObj)
   }
   ```

And run the app!!

Comment: It builds the app but it also throws an error in the console afterwards: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: It may be because your IBOutlet doestnot exist delete that outlet connection and connect properly.

Comment: I reconnected it once again `@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!` but the error is still being displayed.

Comment: I had the same problem as @andufo. The only way I mangled to get rid of this issue was by starting from scratch.

Comment: It maybe because your webView is an optional value. Try adding a `?` to `myWebView?.loadRequest(requestObj);`

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3 doesn't use NS prefix anymore on URL and URLRequest, so the updated code would be:

```
let url = URL(string: "your_url_here")
yourWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 3 you can do it like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Web view load
    let url = URL (string: "http://www.example.com/")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webview.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Remember to add permission at `Info.plist`, add the following values:

[image: Info.plist]

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift 4 or 4.2 You can use like:**

1. Add WKWebView & connect to you view comtroller.
2. Your view is like bellow:

   ```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var wkwebview: WKWebView!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

         let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "**your URL**")!)        
         wkwebview?.load(request)

     }

   }
   ```
3. Allow Allow Arbitrary Loads true  info.plist

   ```
     <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Allow Arbitrary Loads</key>
             <true/>
       </dict>
   ```

   **Note info.plist will look like bellow**

[image]

Comment: Just mention that I needed to add the framework WebKit in the target -> General tab

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3 - Xcode 8.1**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let url = URL (string: "https://ir.linkedin.com/in/razipour1993")
            let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
            myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj)

        }
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add explanation which will help OP and others to understand your answer

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**

```
@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.yourvideo.com")!))
```

Answer (score 5):

**Easy,Tested and working 100%**

Import webkit :

```
import WebKit
```

Assign IBOutlet to webview:

```
var webView : WKWebView!
```

set delegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , WKNavigationDelegate{
```

Write code on viewDidLoad():

```
// loading URL :
let myBlog = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/4600136/mr-javed-multani?tab=profile"
let url = NSURL(string: myBlog)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    // init and load request in webview.
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(request as URLRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    self.view.sendSubview(toBack: webView)
```

Write delegate methods:

```
//MARK:- WKNavigationDelegate

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
print(error.localizedDescription)
}


 func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
print("Strat to load")
    }

 func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
print("finish to load")
}
```

look like:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

> **in swift 5**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
   var webView: WKWebView!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")
      let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
      webView.load(myRequest)
   }
   override func loadView() {
      let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
      webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
      webView.uiDelegate = self
      view = webView
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UIWebView loadRequest: Create NSURLRequest using NSURL object, then passing the request to `uiwebview` it will load the requested URL into the web view.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.google.com");
     let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
     myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
     self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
  }
```

**For more reference:**

**https://sourcefreeze.com/uiwebview-example-using-swift-in-ios/**

Answer (score 3):

Loading URL to WebView is very easy. Just create a WebView in your storyboard and then you can use the following code to load url.

```
    let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.simplifiedios.net");
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(request);
```

As simple as that only 3 lines of codes :)

Ref: [UIWebView Example](https://www.simplifiedios.net/uiwebview-example-load-url/)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 Update** Creating a WebView programatically.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For swift 4.2, 5+**

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
           //Func Gose Here 
          let url = URL(string: link)
          let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
           webView.loadRequest(requestObj)

       }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3.1 and above

```
let url = NSURL (string: "Your Url")
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL);
YourWebViewName.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest)
```

Answer (score 2):

Used Webview in Swift Language

```
let url = URL(string: "http://example.com")
   webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load a page like this :

```
let url: URL = URL(string:"https://google.com")!
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest.init(url: url))
```

Or the one-line approach :

```
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest.init(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))
```

webView is your outlet var.

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
       //Func Gose Here 
      loadUrl()

   } 
 func loadUrl(){

   let url = URL(string: "Url which you want to load(www.google.com)")
   let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
   webView.load(requestObj)
 }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

> Try This

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.apple.com");
myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!));
```

Comment: How can I stop the loading symbol from running? it keeps on running well after the page has been loaded.

Comment: @Marin You need to use start / stop animation activity.