# How to load a webview in a SWIFT based ios App

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am relatively very new to swift. Could you please help me how to load a webview in an ios app based on swift.  Basically I want to load the contents of an external URL in an ios app.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597092/how-to-load-url-in-uiwebview-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")))
webV.delegate = self;
self.view.addSubview(webV)}
```

and if you want use delegate function

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("Webview fail with error \(error)");
}
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -&gt; Bool {
    return true;
}
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
    print("Webview started Loading")
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
    print("Webview did finish load")
```

Answer (score 0):

Before asking your questions research what you're looking, because this question has been answered on many forums.

In the `viewDidLoad()` add the following code. Make sure to connect the WebView to the View and to connect the outlet.

```
   let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.google.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```