# Implement start/pause on UIButton touch up inside

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uibutton

I am writing my first `iOS` app using `Swift` in which, I have a `UIButton` which has Start/Pause functionality. On tapping Start, it will load a image in `UIWebView` and change text to Pause. When tapped on Pause, it will stop loading the `webView`.

I am using the following approach

```
@IBOutlet weak var startPauseButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func startPauseButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

         if  startPauseButton!.currentTitle == "Start"{

            if let htmlURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html" ){
                //  let htmlURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html")
                let requestURL = NSURL(string: htmlURL)
                 let requestObject = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
                webView.sizeToFit()
                 webView.loadRequest(requestObject)
            }else{
                let url =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("video", withExtension: "html")
                 let requestObject = NSURLRequest(URL:url!);
                 webView.loadRequest(requestObject)
            }

            startPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
         }else{
            webView.stopLoading()
            startPauseButton.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }


    }
```

But, this code is changing the text from start to Pause and vice-versa. I am unable to load the resources on `webView`

Upon executing below code,

```
 @IBOutlet weak var startPauseButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func startPauseButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

      //  if  startPauseButton!.currentTitle == "Start"{

            if let htmlURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html" ){
                //  let htmlURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html")
                let requestURL = NSURL(string: htmlURL)
                 let requestObject = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
                webView.sizeToFit()
                 webView.loadRequest(requestObject)
            }else{
                let url =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("video", withExtension: "html")
                 let requestObject = NSURLRequest(URL:url!);
                 webView.loadRequest(requestObject)
            }

            startPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
     /*   }else{
            webView.stopLoading()
            startPauseButton.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
*/

    }
```

I have observed, **that on second tap of the button, the view is loaded in `webView`**. How do I overcome this second tab event make change it to first tab and achieve this functionality ?

**EDIT 1**

On Executing

```
 @IBAction func startPauseButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        println("button has been tapped \(startPauseButton!.titleForState(.Normal))")
     //   if startPauseButton!.titleForState(.Normal) == "Start" {
            if let htmlURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html") {
                let requestObject = NSURLRequest(URL: htmlURL)
                webView.sizeToFit()
                webView.loadRequest(requestObject)
            }else{
                let url =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("video", withExtension: "html")
                let requestObject = NSURLRequest(URL:url!);
                webView.loadRequest(requestObject)
            }

            startPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    /*    }else{
            webView.stopLoading()
            startPauseButton.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }*/
    }
```

The following is the output
`button has been tapped Optional("Start")
button has been tapped Optional("Pause")//here the webview is getting loaded
button has been tapped Optional("Pause")
button has been tapped Optional("Pause")`

Comment: Can by any chance, `htmlURL` or `url` be `nil`?

Comment: @ozgur yes, it can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading webview as explained in this stackoverflow thread -

[How to load URL in UIWebView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597092/how-to-load-url-in-uiwebview-in-swift)