# Is there a way to load URLRequest in UIWebView without specifying (http|https) in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, uiwebview, request, load

I want to get web pages links from the user, and load them using UIWebView, but I don't want the user to have to specify the "http(s)://www." part.
Like the known web browsers, they don't force you to write that part.

Answer (score 0):

From the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597092/how-to-load-url-in-uiwebview-in-swift) it looks like you can load a webpage without specifying `http://` in the URL.

If you want to let the user do what he/she wants and then eventually add `http(s)://` yourself (if it's missing), this can be easily done by checking whether the user's URL has a `http://` (or `https://`) at the start with String's [`.hasPrefix(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540100-hasprefix), and add it if it's not there.

Comment: I saw the answer you referred to before I post my question, but it didn't work with swift 3 / xcode 8.3. the problem is that I don't know what address the user will enter so I don't know does it use http or https, I found a solution though, I check like you said, if it doesn't have the scheme, I add "http://" always, and it works even with sites that use https, I'm not sure whether this is the best solution, but it's working, thanks for your help

Comment: If you scroll a bit down you'll see one with written swift 3 :)

Comment: I meant that webview.loadRequest() doesn't load a request having a url without "http(s)://" part.

Comment: Oh, ok. So, as I've written in my answer, you just need to make a control of the url and add ``http://`` if it's not there yet :)

Comment: yes, but this works only if I added "http://", but if I added "https://", sites that doesn't use the secure protocol won't load. I feel I'm not able to make my self clear :), thanks for the help anyway :). I also check with NSRegularExperssion "https?://", so I can check user input once.