# Getting Webview URL from textField in Swift

Tags: swift, web, view, uiwebview

I have a picker view that populates a `textField` with a `URL` from an array. I would like the user to select an option from the picker view which then opens up the `webView` with the supplied address in the `textField`.  Is that possible?

Is there a more efficient or easier way to do this?

**The only code I have is for the PickerView populating the `textField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have code for the UIPickerview selection that fills the textField value.

So now once user select the value from UIPickerView first fill the textfield and navigate it to webviewController that contains the String varialbe for URL.

Pass the selected value as String while navigation like push the view controlller.

and follow the link for the load URL in webview:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192075/4600136